# Can I embed class objects into strings if class has `__toString` method?

Tags: php, class, tostring

If I have a class which looks something like this

```
class MyClass {
    private $myvar;

    public function __construct($myvar) {
        $this->myvar = $myvar;
    }

    public function getMyVar() {
        return $this->myvar;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "from toString: " . $this->myvar;
    }
}
```

And then I want to use my class like this

```
$myclass = new MyClass("myvar value");
echo "Embedded class into a string: $myclass";
```

From above code I would expect this output

```
Embedded class into a string: from toString: myvar value
```

Comment: Yes, just fix a typo in the `__toString()` method: `return "from toString: $myvar";` --> `return "from toString: $this->myvar";`

Comment: My bad. In original code concatenation was with dot. When I created the question I accidentally wrote it wrong.

Comment: Have you tested your code? It should work then

Comment: I have. It doesn't

Comment: It doesn't work how? Blank screen? Unexpected output?

Comment: Never mind. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is:

```
public function __toString() {
    return "from toString: " . $this->myvar;
}
```

Because `$myvar` in the scope of `__toString` function is **not defined**.

A simple fiddle is here https://3v4l.org/YFctl